# Can I simply delete the File Entity folder from Modules if I am using Media 7.x-1.3

Tags: media, files

When I try to create new content with a linked YouTube video I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_info_file_types() in /home/setstart/public_html/sites/all/modules/media/media.module on line 1084

I have inherited a site that use Media 7.x-1.3

I see that the following Module is also installed - File Entity 7.x-2.0-unstable7

I see from the following threads that the file entity submodule within Media should be used not the standalone one.

http://drupal.org/node/1516804

http://drupal.org/node/1850324

So it looks like File Entity 7.x-2.0-unstable7 should never have been installed.

Can I simply remove the independent File entity module? I see a lot of other modules state they depend on it (so I can't disable it from admin screen)

If not what is my best option? Upgrade to Media 2.x?

Comment: Deleting the folder outright will leave your site in a pretty miserable state (unusable until you fix the database manually), so I would highly recommend you don't do that. The best course of action would be to disable/uninstall all modules that are dependant on the erroneous file entity module; then you can remove that one cleanly, and put in whatever version is appropriate for the version of Media that you're using before re-enabling everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have backups from before the 2.x version of File entity was installed? That would be the ideal solution because frankly, things are bad. You can't just remove the File entity 2.x module directory, because at this point the module has been installed and your data is at quite a dirty state. The only real solution is to try an in-UI disable/uninstall of File entity and any Media related modules to try and get your site to a more clean state before again installing and enabling the proper versions you need/want.